# Modified Google oauth login_hint parameter forces to reload the page instead of logging in

Tags: oauth, google-drive-api

We are using OAuth in our apps to login to repositories such as Google Drive, OneDrive and Box.

We allow the option for the customer to create a default user, so we  use login_hint parameter to pre-populate the default user. Since the box with pre-populated username is editable, if the  customer decides to modify the username, and tries to login with a different username the page is reloaded with the default username again,  instead of logging in. On the second attempt the user is able to login with the new username.

Is this a known behavior? I would expect the user to be able to login the first time. This also works inconsistent, sometimes user is able to login with modified username from the first attempt.

Comment: I am getting the same behavior, except repeatedly attempting to select the not-default email never succeeds. I have only seen this behavior when the default email is on a gapps domain and I attempt to log in with an email that is not on that domain.